# How to use User Defaults with a boolean to check if a function has run?

Tags: ios, swift4

I have a function that I only want to run once everytime someone opens up my project for the first time. How can I fix my code so that it runs my function only once and every other time the value is set to false. Any explanations would be very helpful.

```
// seedToDataBase()
    var seed = seedToDataBase()
    orderMyAnime()
    do{
    let firstRun = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: seed) as Bool
    if !firstRun {
        //run your function
        seedToDataBase()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: seed)
        }
    }catch {
        print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
    }
```

This is the function that I'm calling:

```
func seedToDataBase()
{
    var seedAnime: AnimeObjectMO!
    for o in managedAnime{
        if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate){
            seedAnime = AnimeObjectMO(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)
            seedAnime.aName = o.aName
            seedAnime.aRating = o.aRating
            seedAnime.aRanking = o.aRanking
            seedAnime.aDescription = o.aDescription
            //newAnime.aImage = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: addAnimeImage.text!)!, 1.0)!) as Data!
            seedAnime.aImage = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(o.aImage)!) as Data!


            appDelegate.saveContext()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add seed as a String like "seed"  in this line UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: seed) retrive using that key only.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code when you open the app that time you return false value in userdefault than after call the function            



 let hasLaunchedKey = "CallFunction"
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                var hasLaunched = defaults.bool(forKey: hasLaunchedKey)

                if !hasLaunched {
                    defaults.set(true, forKey: hasLaunchedKey)
                }


        func seedToDataBase()
        {
            var seedAnime: AnimeObjectMO!
            for o in managedAnime{
                if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate){
                    seedAnime = AnimeObjectMO(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)
                    seedAnime.aName = o.aName
                    seedAnime.aRating = o.aRating
                    seedAnime.aRanking = o.aRanking
                    seedAnime.aDescription = o.aDescription
                    //newAnime.aImage = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: addAnimeImage.text!)!, 1.0)!) as Data!
                    seedAnime.aImage = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(o.aImage)!) as Data!


                    appDelegate.saveContext()
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is almost correct, just the `key` part is wrong.

Your `var seed = seedToDataBase()` makes a new instance every time it is called. So seed is not constant and its different everytime that's why your code is not working.

`UserDefault`'s key should be unique, so you should write some `String` name which is not going to change and you should not use that name for other `UserDefault` operations.

Change your code to this :

```
// seedToDataBase()
    var seed = seedToDataBase()
    orderMyAnime()
    do{
    let firstRun = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "SomeKeyName")
    if !firstRun {
        //run your function
        seedToDataBase()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "SomeKeyName")
        }
    }catch {
        print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let hasRunAppOnceKey = "hasRunAppOnceKey"
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if defaults.bool(forKey: hasRunAppOnceKey) == false {
   // Some code you want to run on first use...
   defaults.set(true, forKey: hasRunAppOnceKey)

} else {
   // Some code you want to run on every other time...
}
```